# Xamarin.forms How change View properties at runtime

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout {

    Spacing = 0,
    Children = 
    {
        new Label
        {
            Text = "StackLayout",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            FontSize = 20
        }
    }

}
```

Whats the best way to change the properties of the space and the FontSize at runtime ?

Comment: u have sizeChanged event available with any VisualElement , 
there you can get layout access and all the children to modify at runtime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a reference to your StackLayout, so to change it's properties you would just do:

```
stackLayout.Spacing = 10;
```

To change your Label, you need to keep a reference to it:

```
Label label = new Label
        {
            Text = "StackLayout",
            HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
            FontSize = 20
        };

StackLayout stackLayout = new StackLayout {

    Spacing = 0,
    Children = 
    {
      label
    }
}
```

Then you can modify it at runtime with

```
label.FontSize = 30;
```